# How to avoid having clause into query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working in this query that runs succesfully

```
select 
hash,
SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) as today,
sum(DATE(TIMESTAMP) between DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and  DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as last_week

from behaviour

group by hash
having last_week > 0 and today > last_week
order by today desc
```

and I am trying to optimize it.

I am trying this to avoid the `last_week>0` into the having clause without any luck. I get an "invalid use of group function"

```
select 
hash,
SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) as today,
sum(DATE(TIMESTAMP) between DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and  DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as last_week

from behaviour
where 
and (sum(DATE(TIMESTAMP) between DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 4 DAY) and  DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) > 0)

group by hash
having today > last_week
order by today desc
```

How can I optimize it? Because in a big table it takes about 1 minute to execute.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to filter *before* doing the aggregation:

```
select hash,
       sum(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) as today,
       sum(DATE(TIMESTAMP) between DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as last_week
from behaviour
where timestamp >= curdate() - interval 7 day
      timestamp < curdate() + interval 1 day
group by hash
having today > last_week and last_week > 0
order by today desc;
```

This reduces the volume of data needed for the `group by` -- and that should significantly improve performance.  You might be able to further improve performance with an index on `(timestamp, hash)`.

You still need the `having` clause because you want additional filters on the results.  The performance gain is from filtering before the aggregation, though.

Comment: Hi thank you, however in my question I filter last_week > 0. If I remove this from my query, we get the same results. But it is crucial to have it.

Comment: @EnexoOnoma . . . You can still include that in the `having` clause.

Comment: @EnexoOnoma . . . I interpreted your question about being about performance.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because the first query was 1 min + 13 sec, and the optimized is 13 sec only!